# how to search lambda expressions in java file in openGrok

Tags: java, lambda, opengrok

I want to search in the code repository in how many Java files does the lambda expression is used.
I want to search it on open Grok instead of GitHub.

What I am trying now is if I take a example of 
http://bxr.su/

I am setting values of 
Full Search to : "-> {"
Definition  : stream
File path : . java

But not getting exact results.
Can anyone help me get the exact results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow discussion on
https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/issues/1511
that is a better place

Comment: OK Thanks. You can also use Structural Search feature in Intellij Idea to search for Lambda.